# Place markers on googlemaps exactly on road. (iOS,ObjectiveC)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a project in which there is GoogleMap and I want to place some markers on the map that are say 1km away from me randomly. I want these points to be placed exactly on roads. I have tried so many answers from stackOverFlow and referred some blogs related to googlemaps but I couldn't get any codes that meets my requirements. It will be very helpful if someone helps me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am badly waiting for any replies from someone who is very much familiar with googlemaps sdk.